# template form angular combined with *ngFor

Tags: angular, forms, ngfor

I want to display a form for every match coming up:
so I have a `*ngFor` for every match creating a form with a submit button.
first problem:
If I click submit the form log shows the values of the first submitted form only. It looks like angular,.. or I is confused with the `*ngFor` and submit.

Do I have to add something so Angular knows the submit button is linked to this one form?

Second problem:

How can I add the info `{{match.id}}` to every created form?

HTML

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ngtemplate *ngFor="let match of matches">
      <td>{{ match.matchdate | date: "EEEE, MMMM d, y, h:mm" }}h</td>

      <td scope="row">
        <a href="#" class="text-dark">
          {{ match.hometeam_id.name }} - {{ match.awayteam_id.name }}
        </a>
      </td>

      <td>
        <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
          <select 
            class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" 
            type="number" 
            id="homeTeamBet" 
            ngModel
            name="homeTeamBet _{{ match.id }}" 
            required
          >
            <option *ngFor="let num of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" [value]="num">
              {{ num }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <select 
            class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" 
            type="number" 
            id="awayTeamBet" 
            ngModel 
            name="awayTeamBet"
            required
          >
            <option *ngFor="let num of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]" [value]="num">
              {{ num }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <button class="btn" [disabled]="!f.valid" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </td>

      <td>{{ match.status }} /// {{ match.id }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use button click instead of form submit. The following will be the code:

.html

```
<button class="btn" [disabled]="!f.valid" (click)="onSubmit(match)">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

.ts

```
onSubmit(match){
// write you code here to use match.id etc.
}
```